# recover external hdd after using dd

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 1TB external HDD with no partition. I did a dd command and have overwritten 3gb to my HDD before i cancelled the operation. When I plug the HDD to my PC it can't recognize the HDD and asks me if i want to format it.

What I want is to see my folders arranged as it was even if some files got corrupted. Can I achieve that? I don't want to recover the remaining files and lose the directories and filenames.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: One way would be to try to restore the partition and then perform file recovery. The second way is to simply run a block-based recovery tool that searches through your entire disk.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What was the original situation? Did the external disk have a partition and data? After using dd and writing to the external disk, now you don't have a partition anymore?

Answer (score 3):

If you overwrote a partition, and now want to restore data, and can't mount the disk, you have a problem. First thing to do is not to write to that disk anymore. You can use a utility like Photorec to recover files on that disk. If the partition table is overwritten, which seems to be the case, filenames and file dates are gone. If you have a backup, use that. You might need another disk to write all data to.

[**Photorec**](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) can recover probably anything except those 3GB. I've used it with a formatted disk, and was amazed how much I could find back. Since then I encrypt all my disks.

Comment: HI, my hdd is used in Windows so its NTFS. But when I did DD it must have turned the 3gb into Linux filesystem. Is there a way to isolate the 3gb and make a partition for it. Then make another partition for the rest of the files. Or is the filenames and dates of all my files located in the beginning of the HDD and thus overwritten, as you have mention?

Comment: So it's finally clear that this is a Windows problem. Forget about the 3GB. You've clearly copied that from another hard disk, and can do that again. You can try to recover the NTFS disk. Photorec is a tool to do that, or use a backup. Then reformat the complete disk.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I used dd in Ubuntu, to transfer files from there to my external HDD. So in my case, is there no way to access the files with the file names and directories intact? Photorec was able to recover the files but lost the filenames. I have a lot of files, so it will take so much time to rearrange and rename them like before. I also have a partial backup of the HDD so I wont lose everything. But I hate to miss some files I have in the disk.

Comment: After finding files with the restore photorec, how do you get them so you can access them?  Once it has scanned the hard drive and found them.

Comment: You need another disk to write to. Files will be named like FILE00001, FILE00002 etc if I remember correctly, so filenames will be lost, but extensions like pdf and doc will be recovered.